# Is there a way to align the navbar text to the center using flex?

Tags: html, css

I relly appreciate someone looking over this and letting me know the solution.

Ignore the colors as I am just trying to learn CSS. I have tried to make my navbar 100 px high but that has thrown my li to the top. how would I go about getting the content to center in the navbar? I have tried using align-items: center; and justify-content: center; in the 'li's'.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}


.top {
    background-color: darkseagreen;
    height: 100px;
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    margin: 0;
}

li {
    background-color: darkslateblue;
    padding: 20px;
}

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.push {
    margin-left: auto;
}

.cover {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    grid-column: 1/-1;
    grid-row: 2/3;
}

.javascript {
    background-color: crimson;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 3/4;
}

.secondrow {
    background-color: darkolivegreen;
    grid-column: 1/-1;
    grid-row: 4/5;
}
```

```html
<nav class="top">
    <ul class="navbar">
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li class="push"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="cover">
    <div><h1>Cover</h1></div>
</div>
<div class="javascript"><h1>Javascript</h1></div>
<div class="secondrow"><h1>Second row</h1></div>
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your current snippet isn't that far off target, and you have the right idea to use `justify-content` here.

> The [`justify-content`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp) property aligns the flexible container's items when the items do not use all available space on the main-axis (horizontally).

The problem you're running into, is the fact that you want your final `li` element to be right aligned instead of centered with the other two. While this is possible, using `margin-left: auto` isn't the proper solution for it. By using `margin-left: auto` on the final `li` element, you're telling that element to create as big of a margin as it possibly can, filling the remaining space on the main axis of the parent element. This forces your other two elements to the left hand side of your `nav` element, and negates the use of `justify-content: center`.

My recommendation would be to absolutely position the final `li` element within the `nav` element, and use a [media query](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) to bring it back to relative positioning once the left edge touches the next element in line.

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
}

.top {
 background-color: darkseagreen;
 height: 100px;
}
.navbar {
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 width: 100%;
 list-style: none;
 font-size: 0.7em;
 margin: 0;
}
li {
 background-color: darkslateblue;
 padding: 20px;
}
a {
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.push {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
}
.cover {
 background-color: cornflowerblue;
 grid-column: 1/-1;
 grid-row: 2/3;
}
.javascript {
 background-color: crimson;
 grid-column: 1/2;
 grid-row: 3/4;
}
.secondrow {
 background-color: darkolivegreen;
 grid-column: 1/-1;
 grid-row: 4/5;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 355px) {
 .push { position: relative; }
}
```

```html
<nav class="top">
 <ul class="navbar">
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
  <li class="push"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>

<div class="cover">
 <div>
  <h1>Cover</h1>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="javascript">
 <h1>Javascript</h1>
</div>
<div class="secondrow">
 <h1>Second row</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but I wanted the content centered vertically and the `.push` to be aligned to the far right still.

Comment: @jonno182 I'm done updating my answer, does that solution work for you?

Comment: Hi thanks for taking the time but I wanted the purple boxes centered on the green

Comment: @jonno182 I created a second answer which hopefully answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

`align-items: center;` and `justify-content: center;` have to be properties of the element with `display: flex;`, .navbar in your case.

However, the property of .push `margin-left:auto` is also pushing the previous li-s to the left so .push has as big margin-left as it can. If you remove that property all three will be in the middle.

Then, I would try with absolute positioning on .push to position it on the right.

Answer (score 0):

The navbar now in it correct position

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="top">
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
            <li class="push"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="cover">
        <div>
            <h1>Cover</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="javascript">
        <h1>Javascript</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="secondrow">
        <h1>Second row</h1>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}


.top {
    background-color: darkseagreen;
    height: 100px;
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: darkslateblue;
}

li {
    padding: 20px;
}

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.push {}

.cover {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    grid-column: 1/-1;
    grid-row: 2/3;
}

.javascript {
    background-color: crimson;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 3/4;
}

.secondrow {
    background-color: darkolivegreen;
    grid-column: 1/-1;
    grid-row: 4/5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm creating a second answer based on your comments because I think there was some confusion. It now seems that your intent is to center the elements vertically within the `nav` element, and you have the right idea to use `align-items` for this. The problem is, your `nav` element doesn't have any height to it, so `align-items` is negated. To fix this, give your `nav` element some height:

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
}

.top {
 background-color: darkseagreen;
 height: 100px;
}
.navbar {
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 list-style: none;
 font-size: 0.7em;
 margin: 0;
}
li {
 background-color: darkslateblue;
 padding: 20px;
}
a {
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.push {
 margin-left: auto;
}
.cover {
 background-color: cornflowerblue;
 grid-column: 1/-1;
 grid-row: 2/3;
}
.javascript {
 background-color: crimson;
 grid-column: 1/2;
 grid-row: 3/4;
}
.secondrow {
 background-color: darkolivegreen;
 grid-column: 1/-1;
 grid-row: 4/5;
}
```

```html
        <nav class="top">
            <ul class="navbar">
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                <li class="push"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    
        <div class="cover">
            <div>
                <h1>Cover</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="javascript">
            <h1>Javascript</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="secondrow">
            <h1>Second row</h1>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add align-items property to `.top`(nav) because `ul` is group of `li` and present in `.top` & give 100% width to navbar:

```
.top {
    height: 100px;
    display:flex;
    /**justify-content:center;**/
    align-items: center;
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}


.top {
    background-color: darkseagreen;
    height: 100px;
    display:flex;
    /**justify-content:center;**/
    align-items: center;
}
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    width:100%;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    margin: 0;
}

li {
    background-color: darkslateblue;
    padding: 20px;
}

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.push {
    margin-left: auto;
}

.cover {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    grid-column: 1/-1;
    grid-row: 2/3;
}

.javascript {
    background-color: crimson;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 3/4;
}

.secondrow {
    background-color: darkolivegreen;
    grid-column: 1/-1;
    grid-row: 4/5;
}
```

```html
<nav class="top">
    <ul class="navbar">
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li class="push"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="cover">
    <div><h1>Cover</h1></div>
</div>
<div class="javascript"><h1>Javascript</h1></div>
<div class="secondrow"><h1>Second row</h1></div>
```